# Emulate key press in browser

Tags: c#, key, cefsharp

Is there any way to emulate a key press in the CefSharp browser. I've had a look through the documentation but couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using Keyevent and use SendKeyEvent to the element you want to press?

Here is documentation of the Keyevent: https://cefsharp.github.io/api/51.0.0/html/T_CefSharp_KeyEvent.htm

I don't know much about cefsharp but I'll help you as much as I can.